# How to access a member variable that doesn't change

Tags: visualforce

I have a member variable that doesn't change (i think it should be static final). How do i access it in my vf page? Here's what I'm doing, and though it works, it seems verbose, and wrong....

```
public String myString
{
    get
    {
        if (myString == null){myString = 'blah';}
        return myString;
    }
    set;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many possible approaches. One would be to return some sort of `final` variable. You can also just define the `getter`, with no need to `set`.

```
public static final String SOME_CONSTANT = 'foo';
final String someVariable = 'bar';

public String aConstant { get { return SOME_CONSTANT; } }
public String aVariable { get { return someVariable; } }
public String aProperty { get { return 'Blah'; } } // most concise

public String getSomeProperty() { return 'Blah'; }
// etc.
```

---

Note that you cannot make properties final when you use getter syntax:

```
public final String someProperty { get { return 'Some Value'; } }
```

The above code will fail to compile with this error:

> Methods are final by default, Use virtual to declare methods that can be overriden

Comment: Thanks! Why can't the most concise version be static final as well?

Comment: @user Methods are final by default. Getters define an implicit method.

Comment: I'm sorry- could you please elaborate on that, or point me to some documentation if you prefer?

Comment: @user11235813 See the updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do this by changing the myString to a method.

```
public String getmyString(){return 'Blah';}
```

On the Visualforce page use 'myString'. I think that this will work.

Comment: so make myStr static final? and make a seperate getter?